# How to make a clean removal of anaconda without anaconda-clean?

Tags: windows, anaconda, conda

Sorry because i know that this topic has already been explored many times, but i couldn't find any solution to my problem.
I'm on windows 10 (if my company was working with linux i wouldn't have this type of problem --')
To sum up i tried to unsinstall Anaconda (the usual windows way by unstalling the application), to reinstall and make a fresh new installation (i'm naïve i was hopping this would be simple)...

Then when i launched spyder and the anaconda navigator, it told me that the shortcuts was invalid and that i needed to delete it.

Why not after all i just uninstall reinstall, i just needed to create new shortcuts using directly the application of spyder or anaconda that i would find in my computer...

But nothing worked. When i found the application (spyder or anaconda navigator) it didn't work, i wasn't able to launch anything. My anaconda prompt just seems to be a classic windows terminal (commands as conda, pip or jupyter just doesn't exist anymore).

This is the beginning....

Currently i have tried many thing (uninstall reinstall 4 times, delete folders myself etc..) but nothing worked and i'm affraid i totaly broke Anaconda..

Do you have any ideas on how i can get out of this mess ?

PS: of course to make the problem harder, i used a proxy to install package so i used pip for all my libraries and i'm not sure i can install with conda (whatever the conda commands doesn't work now :'( )

Comment: _delete folders myself_ What folders have you deleted? I would imagine that removing it the standard way and then deleting any folder which includes "conda" or "anaconda" would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that i finally achieve to delete all the concerning file and redo the installation ^^